# HMS or Huawei: I am advertising my app published in App Gallery through Huawei Ads and I do not want to display my competitor ads in my app

Tags: ads, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ads

example: If developer( partner  app is in short video category, partner  integrate ads kit, now while ads delivery, the app should display all type of ads other than short video category.

please anybody help on this..

Answer (score 0):

According to [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/monetize/mediashielding-0000001062287179), you could sign in to HUAWEI Ads Publisher Console, click **My apps**, and click **Block ads** in the **Operation** column of one app to achieve this.

[image]

[image]

For example you select **By category**, none of the ads belonging to the category you set will be displayed in your ad unit. Generally, this option is used to block the ads of competitors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is an option in HUAWEI Ads Publisher Console to block Ads related to specific app.

Ad blocking can be done by two levels ,developer can choose any one based on their requirement.

1.App Level

2.Account Level.

Once after choosing the level , Click By app from the tab and Add package names and click save.
[image]

Please refer below links for more detail:

Account level blocking: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/monetize/accountshielding-0000001062689335

App level blocking: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/monetize/mediashielding-0000001062287179